# Unable to add the Wikitude SDK to the project by installing the Wikitude PhoneGap Plugin

Tags: android, cordova, wikitude

I am trying to  add the Wikitude SDK to the project by installing the Wikitude PhoneGap Plugin

The command I gave in the console is

```
G:\AUG\Test Project 02\AugmentedRealityProject>cordova plugin add https://github
.com/Wikitude/wikitude-phonegap.git
```

but it gives following error.

```
Error: Command failed: Cloning into 'C:\Users\Nadeesha\AppData\Local\Temp\plugma
    n\git\1414480358426'...
    fatal: early EOF
    fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly
    fatal: index-pack failed
    error: RPC failed; result=56, HTTP code = 200

    at ChildProcess.exithandler (child_process.js:648:15)
    at ChildProcess.emit (events.js:98:17)
    at maybeClose (child_process.js:756:16)
    at Socket.<anonymous> (child_process.js:969:11)
    at Socket.emit (events.js:95:17)
    at Pipe.close (net.js:465:12)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Simply I have disable my virus guard for 10 minutes, All the content download into the project without giving an error.I think my virus guard detecting this as a malicious activity and preventing the download.